# How can I call to scope when submit modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui-bootstrap in my project and working with bootstrap modal. But I'm having a problem with my modal when I submit I can't call to scope and I got a error "**$scope.testAlert is not a function**"

controller:

```
$scope.open = function () {
        $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'userModal.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, user) {
                $scope.user = user;

                $scope.save = function () {

                    var editUser = userService.updateUser($scope.user);
                    editUser.then(function () {
                        getAllUsers();
                        $scope.testAlert();
                    })

                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                user: function () {
                    return $scope.user;
                }
            }
        });
    }

$scope.testAlert = function () {
        alert("Blah blah");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.testAlert is on the $scope of the main controller rather than the modal controller.  You need to move it like this:

```
$scope.open = function() {
  $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'userModal.html',
    controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, user) {
      $scope.user = user;

      $scope.save = function() {

        var editUser = userService.updateUser($scope.user);
        editUser.then(function() {
          getAllUsers();
          $scope.testAlert();
        })

        $uibModalInstance.close();

        $scope.testAlert = function() {
          alert("Blah blah");
        }
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      user: function() {
        return $scope.user;
      }
    }
  });
```

}